# Rank of a matrix in Ellenberg/Gijswijt proof

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, polynomials, proof-explanation, finite-fields

In a paper by Ellenberg and Gijswijt on the cap set problem, the proof of proposition 2 relies on the claim that certain matrices have rank 1. This is not obvious to me. Why?

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09223v1.pdf

The matrices in question are indexed by a subset $A\subset \mathbb{F}_q^n$, with $a,b$ entry

$$m(a)F(b)$$

where $m$ is a monomial of degree at most $d\leq 2n$, and $F$ a polynomial of degree at most $2n-d$. Furthermore, each variable appears with degree at most $q-1$ in any term of $m(x)F(x)$

Comment: Every matrix of the form $M_{ij} = a_i b_j$ has rank $1$, for any sequences $a_i, b_j$ whatsoever (and in fact, conversely, every rank $1$ matrix takes this form).There are several ways to see this, but maybe it's clearer with the irrelevant details stripped away.

Comment: That clarifies things massively. I assumed I was missing some property of the degrees of polynomials involved

Comment: What Qiaochu said. For example all the rows of $M$ are scalar multiples of $(F(b_1),F(b_2),\ldots)$. And all the columns of $M$ are scalar multiples of $(m(a_1),m(a_2),\ldots)^T$.